# Openbsd 5.7: IPv6 advertisement not working

Tags: ipv6, openbsd, pf

--**context**--

I have a Sokeris with 8 interfaces: em0 is connected to a bridge router (ISP) and em2 is connected to my DMZ network (web servers).
I got from my ISP a /56 prefix and 2 DNS IPs but no gateway IP.

--**problem**--

My em0 is not getting a public IPv6 (only link local).

--**troubleshooting**--

I search online and found out that:
- OBSD 5.7 has no more need for rtsol since it has been included in kernel.
- IPv6 forwarding has to be disabled for router advertisement to be used. (this will cause problem since I have to forward IPv6 between em2 and em0 for customers to access web servers)

tcpdump gives below output: tcpdump -vvnli em0 icmp6

```
05:09:27.184840 fe80::1 > ff02::1: icmp6: router advertisement(chlim=64, MO router_ltime=1800, reachable_time=0, retrans_time=0)(src lladdr: fc:48:ef:c3:41:fe)(mtu: mtu=1500) [icmp6 cksum ok] [class 0xc0] (len 32, hlim 255)
05:10:26.292927 fe80::200:24ff:fed1:86bc > ff02::2: icmp6: router solicitation (src lladdr: 00:00:24:d1:86:bc) [icmp6 cksum ok] (len 16, hlim 255)
05:10:27.185659 fe80::1 > ff02::1: icmp6: router advertisement(chlim=64, MO router_ltime=1800, reachable_time=0, retrans_time=0)(src lladdr: fc:48:ef:c3:41:fe)(mtu: mtu=1500) [icmp6 cksum ok] [class 0xc0] (len 32, hlim 255)
05:10:42.962787 fe80::1 > fe80::3a2c:4aff:fe07:b64e: icmp6: neighbor sol: who has fe80::3a2c:4aff:fe07:b64e(src lladdr: fc:48:ef:c3:41:fe) [icmp6 cksum ok] [class 0xc0] (len 32, hlim 255)
05:11:21.187692 fe80::1 > ff02::1: icmp6: router advertisement(chlim=64, MO router_ltime=1800, reachable_time=0, retrans_time=0)(src lladdr: fc:48:ef:c3:41:fe)(mtu: mtu=1500) [icmp6 cksum ok] [class 0xc0] (len 32, hlim 255)
05:11:26.292308 fe80::200:24ff:fed1:86bc > ff02::2: icmp6: router solicitation (src lladdr: 00:00:24:d1:86:bc) [icmp6 cksum ok] (len 16, hlim 255)
05:11:27.186303 fe80::1 > ff02::1: icmp6: router advertisement(chlim=64, MO router_ltime=1800, reachable_time=0, retrans_time=0)(src lladdr: fc:48:ef:c3:41:fe)(mtu: mtu=1500) [icmp6 cksum ok] [class 0xc0] (len 32, hlim 255)
```

--**configuration**--

/etc/hostname.em0

```
inet XXXXXXXXXXXX 255.255.255.128 NONE media 1000baseTX
inet6 autoconf
```

No rtadvd, dhcpc6 files

PF doesn't have impact since result is same with or without it.

sysctl |grep inet6

```
net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=0
net.inet6.ip6.redirect=0
net.inet6.ip6.hlim=64
net.inet6.ip6.mrtproto=103
net.inet6.ip6.maxfragpackets=200
net.inet6.ip6.log_interval=5
net.inet6.ip6.hdrnestlimit=10
net.inet6.ip6.dad_count=1
net.inet6.ip6.auto_flowlabel=1
net.inet6.ip6.defmcasthlim=1
net.inet6.ip6.use_deprecated=0
net.inet6.ip6.rr_prune=5
net.inet6.ip6.v6only=1
net.inet6.ip6.maxfrags=200
net.inet6.ip6.mforwarding=0
net.inet6.ip6.multipath=0
net.inet6.ip6.multicast_mtudisc=0
net.inet6.ip6.neighborgcthresh=2048
net.inet6.ip6.maxifprefixes=16
net.inet6.ip6.maxifdefrouters=16
net.inet6.ip6.maxdynroutes=4096
net.inet6.ip6.dad_pending=0
net.inet6.ip6.mtudisctimeout=600
net.inet6.ip6.ifq.len=0
net.inet6.ip6.ifq.maxlen=256
net.inet6.ip6.ifq.drops=0
net.inet6.icmp6.redirtimeout=600
net.inet6.icmp6.nd6_prune=1
net.inet6.icmp6.nd6_delay=5
net.inet6.icmp6.nd6_umaxtries=3
net.inet6.icmp6.nd6_mmaxtries=3
net.inet6.icmp6.errppslimit=100
net.inet6.icmp6.nd6_maxnudhint=0
net.inet6.icmp6.mtudisc_hiwat=1280
net.inet6.icmp6.mtudisc_lowat=256
net.inet6.icmp6.nd6_debug=0
net.inet6.divert.recvspace=65636
net.inet6.divert.sendspace=65636
```

Has someone encountered the same problem? It may work with wide dhcp client but it's supposed to work out of the box.

Thanks!

Comment: This thread seems relevant: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.openbsd.misc/224283
I am running into exactly the same issue, but I don't feel like recompiling the system to just pick one change which will allow accepting rtadv when ip6.forwarding is ON.

Comment: yes it's also me :) (sent on OBSD ml ^^)